# Why Android's ImageDecoder (introduced in Pie) don't has a public InputStreamSource?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, imagedecoder

Android's new class for decode images, the [ImageDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder), has lots of source types. But not the `createSource(InputStream)` included. There is a similar method `createSource(Resources res, InputStream is)`, but it is hidden(why?).

Now I want to use ImageDecoder to decode an `InputStream`, which is opened from a `ZipFile.getInputStream()` just like `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` does.

So:

1. Why is the method hidden?
2. Is there any alternative so I can use `ImageDecoder` with an `InputStream`? (Cause I don't want to use the old `BitmapFactory`)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the method hidden?

Google has stated that [they do not want to support streams](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74495852#comment3), though they did not elaborate on a reason.

> Is there any alternative so I can use ImageDecoder with an InputStream?

Read the stream into memory, then use `ByteBuffer`, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Maybe I'll still use BitmapFactory... I don't really understand why Google don't want InputStream.